# Remove duplicate values from a list in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

This is a case of duplicate value for which I haven't found a solution.

Let's say we've got the following list:

```
List = [
    (A, B),
    (A, C),
    (B, A),
    (B, C),
    (C, A),
    (C, B)
].
```

A duplicate element would be an element that has exactly the same values in its package - the order doesn't matter.

So after removing the duplicates, the list would look like this:

```
List = [
    (A, B),
    (A, C),
    (B, C),
].
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a straight-forward way (but that doesn't really fully utilise inbuilt predicates):

```
% an item is sorted when the two terms are in standard order of terms
%   note that you use @< and @> when you are comparing things that aren't numbers
sortitem((A, B), Item) :-
    (A @< B,
    Item = (A, B));
    (A @> B,
    Item = (B, A)).

% a list of items is sorted when each of the individual item's terms are sorted (but we
%   don't care if the items themselves are in order)
sortlistitems([], []).
sortlistitems([H|T], List) :-
    sortitem(H, HSorted),
    sortlistitems(T, TSorted),
    List = [HSorted|TSorted].

% sorting with sort/2 removes duplicates and puts the items in order
removeduplicateitems(X, Y) :-
    sortlistitems(X, XSorted),
    sort(XSorted, Y).
```

Testing:

```
?- removeduplicateitems([(a, b), (a, c), (b, a), (b, c),(c, a),(c, b)], X).
X = [ (a, b), (a, c), (b, c)]
```

Comment: nit in sortlistitems/2: It is common to put a unification like 'List = [...]` into the head. `maplist(sortitem, X, XSorted)` would have been as good.

Comment: Also, `removeduplicateitems([(b,a)], [(b,a)])` fails. Not sure OP wanted this.

Comment: @false both of your comments are definitely valid ones.

Answer (score 1):

Write a predicate `same/2` to recognize when two elements are the same independently of the order.

Write a predicate `member_same/2` (like `member/2`, but with equality replaced by `same/2`) that checks whether an element is a member of a list, irrespective ordering.

Then write a predicate to remove duplicates using `member_same/2`.

BTW, you need to write constants in lower case, upper case is for variables. This could lead to a lot of confusion, because distinct variables can become equal by unification.